# HTTP error 403 in R when requesting many pages (rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a scraper that goes through a list of pages (all from the same site) and either 1. downloads the html/css from each page, or 2. gets me the links which exist within a list item with a particular class. (For now, my code reflects the former.) I'm doing this in R; python returned a 403 error upon the very first get request of the site, so BeautifulSoup and selenium were ruled out. In R, my code works for a time (a rather short one), and then I receive a 403 error, specifically:

"Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403."

I considered putting a Sys.sleep() timer on each item in the loop, but I need to run this nearly 1000 times, so I found that solution impractical. I'm a little stumped as to what to do, particularly since the code *does* work, but only for a short time before it's halted. I was looking into proxies/headers, but my knowledge of either of these is unfortunately rather limited (although, of course, I'd be willing to learn if anyone has a suggestion involving either of these). Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Here's the code for reference:

```
for (i in 1:length(data1$Search)) {
    url = data1$Search[i]
    name = data1$Name[i]
    download.file(url, destfile = paste(name, ".html", sep = ""), quiet = TRUE)
}
```

where data1 is a two column dataframe with the columns "Search" and "Name". Once again, any suggestions are much welcome. Thank you.

Comment: It May be possible that the site is blocking you for posting too many request in a short period of time.  Add the sys.sleep, let it run and go outside and get some coffee or something.

Comment: This was my worry as well. Unfortunately, sleeping it for even 15 seconds between requests isn't enough to placate it (it actually stops after only 3 web pages instead of the 9/10 it can get just straight up). Additionally, this is only part 1; part two would run virtually the same thing, but 12,000 times... To add to my misery, I planned on doing this every day for a while, as I'm trying to collect a dataset that changes over time. Alas...

Comment: Storing the html/css of tens of thousands of pages seems rather wasteful if you are only interested in urls. Perhaps `Rcrawler::LinkExtractor` wrapped in a `tryCatch` could be useful here. As it is now, this is not reproducible

Comment: I'm running two passes. The first is only interested in urls, and from those urls, I'm interested in some of their html content. LinkExtractor is a clever solution for the first round of information, but I'm still stuck on the second round.

Comment: Give us the website, maybe i can help you. If this web has some protection like akamai, forter, datadome. You need to do some things to bypass it.

Comment: The site of interest is streeteasy.com